# Mysql >> 3 tables to one main table

Tags: mysql, database

To all MYSQL gurus

I don't know if this can be done but i would like to  know if there is a way to get all contents of 3 tables that are similar in structure but deferent in data  into one main table so i can just interact with the main table using code.
one curve ball is, the records in the 3 tables are updated not added just updated every 1 sec with new values.

any solutions or ideas is appreciated

Comment: Use a view to make a virtual table.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, i think this may work perfectly, but how can you create a view since the 3 tables have same structure, means same columns ? thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Barmar pointing VIEW feature in MYSQL , at first couldn't create the view because the 3 tables had same structure and mySql keeps throwing Errors... so after little research i found UNION ALL

```
create view NAME_OF_THE_VIEW as SELECT * FROM `FIRST_TABLE` UNION ALL select * from `SECOND_TABLE` UNION ALL select * from  `THIRD_TABLE`;
```

so now i have a view that combines my 3 tables and every updates the 3 tables gets is automatically updated in the VIEW....perfect!!

thank you again Barmar

Comment: Best not to use * on the select. and updates the 3 tables gets is automatically updated in the VIEW. is not strictly true when the view is is invoked it queries the data rather than being updated (ie it's not a materialised view).